# Getting data from a column based on indexes in another column in Pandas

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, indexing

I have a dataframe in which two columns contains lists, first one has the items and second one has the indexes. Like:

```
        A             B

0   [11, 12, 13, 14]    [0, 2, 3, 0]
1   [11, 22]            [1, 0]
2   [9, 7]              [0, 1]
```

I want to create another column that contains elements of Series A based on the index in B, so the resulting series should be like this:

```
     C
0  [11,13,14,11]
1  [22,11]
2  [9,7]
```

Can anyone help please? Many thanks in advance

Comment: B has 0 twice on first row, is that ok?

Comment: Yes, there can be repeatation of indexes, however overall size of both arrays in both columns remains the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using

```
[ np.array(x)[y].tolist() for x , y in  zip(df.A,df.B)]

Out[298]: [[11, 13, 14, 11], [22, 11]]
```

---

After assign

```
df['c']=[ np.array(x)[y].tolist() for x , y in  zip(df.A,df.B)]
df
Out[300]: 
                  A             B                 c
0  [11, 12, 13, 14]  [0, 2, 3, 0]  [11, 13, 14, 11]
1          [11, 22]        [1, 0]          [22, 11]
```

Comment: Thanks but this is not sum. I need the values of A based on index in B

Comment: Thank you so much, you are genius :)

Comment: @Mahdi yw :-) happy coding